# Downloading files via APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, apex

How can I download a file in Oracle Apex?

I have a PACKAGE in the database that, when executed, generates a return text. I need to create a file with the execution result of my PACKAGE printed in it. I haven't found a native function in Apex for downloading, only for uploading to save in the database

Comment: you can use the owa package to do this, here's an example https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2021/03/downloading-streaming-content-with-ords-file-downloads/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try like the example